# How to access a public static variable in a model from a controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, static-variables

Here is the model structure

```
class Misc_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static $type_alphabet        = 'a';
}
```

I am accessing the variable from a Controller, like this:-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once('webservice_common.php');
class Webservice_user extends Webservice_common {

    protected $_data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function preRegistration(){
        $miscObj = new Misc_model;
        $type = $miscObj::$type_numeric;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do in Codeigniter, or is there some other way? In codeigniter, we load models like this:-

```
$this->load->model('misc_model');
```

And for calling a function we write like this:-

```
$this->misc_model->the_function();
```

Is there any other specific way (in Codeigniter) to access public static function from a different controller?

Comment: Why not just `Misc_model::$type_numeric`.  You don't need an instance for static variables.

Comment: Exactly. You load everything as per usual and access the static var as Devon stated.

Comment: @Devon, As far I remember, Misc_model::$type_numeric gave me some error. I will check it and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Model:

```
class Misc_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public static $type_alphabet = 'a';
}
```

Controller:

```
public function preRegistration(){
    $this->load->model('Misc_model');
    $type = Misc_model::type_numeric;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm